# Send keystroke out of Git bash script (windows)

Tags: windows, shell, sh, git-bash, keystroke

I want to send a keystroke (F5) out of a shell script which begins with

```
#!/bin/sh
```

I use Git Bash. How do I do that?

Comment: Looks like you're using "sh" on Windows. Are you using Windows Subsystem for Linux or something else like Git Bash or MSYS?

Comment: I use git and sh is included there.